# Tricky C char pointer issue

Tags: c, pointers

So I'm trying to write a function that will take in two pointers to chars and return a new pointer to their concatenation.  Here's my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * append (char *, char *);

int main(void) {

  char *start = "start";
  char *add = "add";
  char* newString = append(start, add);
  printf("%s\n", newString);
  return 0;
}

char * append(char *start, char *add) {
  char *newArray = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  //get to end of start word
  while (*start != '\0') {
    *newArray = *start;
    newArray++;
    start++;
  }
  while (*add != '\0') {
     *newArray = *add; 
     newArray++;
     add++;
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Two questions:

1) As of now it compiles but nothing gets printed.  I think this is because my append function returns a pointer to the very end of the concatenated characters.  Should I create a temporary character pointer and set it to newArray at the very start (so I can just return that)?  Otherwise, I have to somehow decrement my pointer until I get back to the start.  But there's no value that (like '\0' for the end of a string) that will tell me I'm at the start of the char array...

2) I read that I can't just take sizeof() a char pointer, so I'm not really sure what to pass as my argument to malloc on the first line of my append function.  100 is just a "large enough" magic number which I want to get rid of...

If I *could* take sizeof() a char pointer, I'd just do:

```
char *newArray = malloc(sizeof(strlen(start) + strlen(add)) + 1);
```

Thanks for the help,

bclayman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you need to save a pointer to the beginning of the allocated memory so that you can return it.  Its better to think of that pointer as the "real" pointer and the pointer you increment as you store characters as the temporary, but it really makes no difference -- a pointer is a pointer

2) That is what `strlen` is for -- it tells you the length of the string.  So you want

```
char *newArray = malloc(strlen(start) + strlen(add) + 1);
```

no need for `sizeof` at all.

With all that, you end up with:

```
char *append(char *start, char *add) {
  char *newArray = malloc(strlen(start) + strlen(add) + 1);
  if (!newArray) return 0; // out of memory
  char *copy = newArray;
  //get to end of start word
  while (*start != '\0')
    *copy++ = *start++;
  while (*add != '\0')
    *copy++ = *add++;
  *copy = 0; // add a final NUL terminator 
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: The size of is more complete, you're assuming on the op's architecture has an 8 bit char type.

Comment: @rhubarbdog: by definition, `sizeof(char) == 1` always -- number of bits in a char doesn't enter into it.  There is never any reason to use `sizeof(char)` in a program.